# Hibernate, get user from OneToMany list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have to write a method in which all applications in which the user submits his application will be returned, i.e. in those in which the currently logged in user is listed on the appliedBy list.

ApplicationEntity

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "applied_by_id")
private List<UserEntity> appliedBy;
```

UserEntity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_app_id")
private ApplicationEntity user_applications;
```

In addition, after extracting information from the above bindings, I need to check that the orderState enum is correct, i.e. DELIVERED or FINISHED.

I try do it in this way:

ApplicationRepository

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM ApplicationEntity a join a.appliedBy u where u.id = :userId")
public List<ApplicationEntity> getUserApplications(@Param("userId") UUID userId);
```

ApplicationService

```
List<ApplicationEntity> application = applicationRepository.getUserApplications(user.getId());

application.stream().allMatch(us -> us.equals(OrderState.DELIVERED) || us.equals(OrderState.FINISHED));
```

But it doesn't work :(
Does anyone have an idea on how we could get the user out of `List <UserEntity> appliedBy`?

Answer (score 0):

@Query("SELECT * FROM ApplicationEntity a where a.applied_by_id=:#{#userId}", nativeQuery = true)
 List getUserApplications(@Param("userId") Long userId);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM ApplicationEntity a WHERE a.appliedBy.id = :userID)
```

You don't need the join.